# what's the workflow layer?

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

Recently I'm reading an article  about  http://ardalis.com/n-tier-design-lessons-learned-part-1 which introduce  the  evolution  of n-tier application  but one thing was not explained  is the WorkFlow layer can  anyone  one explain what's the workflow layer and give us a real world application example  with c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.integralds.com/services/docs/workflowtier.htm):

> By creating a **workflow** tier a company has essentially avoided
>   hardcoding workflows into one of the other tiers. By creating a
>   workflow layer, we will gain the added flexibility easily
>   customizability that a tier provides. We will gain improve
>   manageability of the workflow tier by extracting the layer. For
>   example, when the end user requests changes to the workflow, by
>   creating a specific workflow tier and thus isolating the
>   responsibility of workflow the resulting code changes will be
>   minimized to just the workflow tier. The impact on other tiers will be
>   minimized.

Also check **[To Workflow or Not to Workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634901/to-workflow-or-not-to-workflow)**

Comment: your first link was useful but it does not answer my question so if we take a wpf application with mvvm as design pattern and entity framework  which part will represent the workflow layer